# Displaying Message Box in ASP

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I want to display a message box after deletion of a record from MSACCESS. I wrote a code below but it just redirects me to the previous page. I want to display message first then to redirect.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
Dim objConn
Dim objRS
Dim varpnr
varpnr = Request.QueryString("ID")
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source="& _
            "D:\Project.mdb"
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
objRS.Open "Book", objConn, 2, 3

Do Until objRS.EOF
If objRS("PNR") = varpnr Then
objRS.Delete
response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert

('Hello!');</script>")
End If
objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
objConn.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing 
response.redirect "Delete_Entry.asp"
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VBScript redirect is happening server side and hence happening before the JavaScript can execute client side.

You need to do your redirect in JavaScript after the alert. e.g.

```
response.write("<script language=""javascript"">alert ('Hello!'); window.location='Delete_Entry.asp'</script>")
```

Remove the `response.redirect "Delete_Entry.asp"`

Comment: thank you so much .. this code worked. Now i have 1 more problem. Access adds empty rows while deleting the record. How to prevent access from adding empty rows :(

Comment: @YusufM If you can't solve that one, post a new question with the details

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just do something like this?

```
alert "All done." 
response.redirect "Delete_Entry.asp"
```

Comment: No - this is a mix of Classic ASP (server side) and JavaScript (client side). Dijkgraaf's answer pretty much covers what should be done.